# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1235 This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'SUBQUERY in ROW in left expression of IN/ALL/ANY'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

Getting this error:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1235 This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'SUBQUERY in ROW in left expression of IN/ALL/ANY'

I am using PHP Laravel and my query looks like this in PHP:

```
$data->whereHas('books', function ($q) {
    $q->where(
        'id', 
        DB::Raw('(select min(`id`) from books where books_id= `books`.`id`)')
    );
});
```

`whereHas` is executed as exists in SQL as `exists (select * from books`

which is not supported in MariaDB.

How can I replace `whereHas`? I an new to php Laravel.

Comment: please explain what you want to achieve

Comment: Getting this error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1235 This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'SUBQUERY in ROW in left expression of IN\/ALL\/ANY'

Comment: i want to know that you want to achieve, not what error you are getting.

Comment: I want to rewrite my query but does not want to use whereHas which is converted to "exists (select * from ....." and could not be executed in MariaDB. I need something like withCount or something but does not how to write it in Laravel.

This is the query -
$data->whereHas('books', function ($q) {
    $q->where(
        'id', 
        DB::Raw('(select min(`id`) from books where books_id= `books`.`id`)')
    );
});

Comment: i would like to know what you what to achive with the query, not as topic

Comment: You can keep the exists() and avoid the subquery within exists()